# How to compress videos that are taken with webrtc before they go to the server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js

I have a website that uses webrtc and mediarecorder.  The videos user submit is on average about 20min in length. So, my question is what is the best way to compress the videos before the go to the server?

Comment: [MCVE] ?!?!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at H.264 and H.265 video codec.
If you want to use an existing media server, check https://www.kurento.org/

Comment: I will look into this for my site (10ball.org). Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use MediaRecorder, the two knobs you have are:

- your getUserMedia call for controlling video resolution and framerate
- the bitsPerSecond arguments in the [MediaRecorder constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/#dictdef-mediarecorderoptions)

Using VP9 as codec in the constructor where available might also get you a lower bitrate at the same quality.

Note that MediaRecorder is single-pass. Two-pass encoding is typically better so you might want to experiment with reencoding using FFMPEG on the server after upload.